# Strange behavior of Voice Over and Braille board in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, voiceover, braille

In my iPhone application I use Braille board with Voice Over. I have found a problem in ios 7.
This issue is easy to reproduce. I start my application and enter some symbol on Braille board (exept enter symbol). Then, in an application I navigate to another screen. which contains a UITextField element. Then I put focus on this element. Voice over and Braille board say "Double tap to edit" not "Is editing". I find out that this situation appears only if I write some symbol on braille board before. But on main screen there is no a textField element. How can I fix this issue? Please help me, I am trying to fix this issue for three days.

Comment: Is it specific to the Braille board or do you see the same issue if you enter text in the first text field using the on-screen keyboard with Voice Over?